# Blackberry map does not display properly on Blackberry 6 device

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, blackberry, dictionary, blackberry-webworks

I have a blackberry application developed using jQuery Mobile and wrapped in Phone Gap.
There I am trying to open the 'Directions' map as separate while clicking on a button. For that, I have been trying the BB map like mentioned in the page http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments.html.

I call the following script function while clicking.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var args = new blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments(43.26, -80.30);
    blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_MAPS, args);
</script>
```

Also I have included the following feature in config.xml

```
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments" />
```

While clicking, it opens up but , the map is not getting displayed(no grids and lines).

Can any one please help me?

Thanks in advance.